# How to change color of a single button upon click

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter/dart and relatively new to object oriented programming.

I have a simple screen with two blue buttons and when the user clicks on one of these buttons that button should turn green, however, when one of these buttons is clicked both buttons turn green.

How can I fix my code so that only the clicked button changes color.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  Color _buttonColor = Colors.blue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                  RaisedButton(
                    color: _buttonColor,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                       _buttonColor = Colors.green;
                      });
                    },
                  ),

                  RaisedButton(
                    color: _buttonColor,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _buttonColor = Colors.green;
                      });
                    },
                  )

                ],
              ),
            )
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If an answer fixed your issue, remember to mark it as correct. It will help future users with the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a variable for each button color:

**Variables**

```
Color _buttonColor1 = Colors.blue;
Color _buttonColor2 = Colors.red;
```

**Widgets**

```
RaisedButton(
  color: _buttonColor1,
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      _buttonColor1 = Colors.green;
    });
  },
),

RaisedButton(
  color: _buttonColor2,
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      _buttonColor2 = Colors.orange;
    });
  },
)
```

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but shouldn‘t the modified variable being used in the color declarcation of the button widget? Otherwise, the color would remain as it is?

Comment: You're absolutely right. After copy pasting the original code, I forgot to update those variables. I've updated it now. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask, if I have 26 buttons, would 26 different variables still be the best way to code this?

Comment: If the order of your buttons in the view doesn't change, you could have the colors in a List<Color> and access them in each bottom according to the order colorList[0], colorList[12], colorList[25]. And then use the same when changing the color on the setState.

Answer (score 3):

You have `Color _buttonColor = Colors.blue;` you tell both widgets to use `_buttonColor` to set the Color. You set the color property of both `RaisedButtons` to point to the same variable `color: _buttonColor`.

In `setState()` both widgets will be rebuilt with the color green.

I'd suggest using two top variables like `_buttonColor1` and `_buttonColor2`. And use one of the variables in one `RaisedButton` widget and the second in the second `RaisedButton` widget. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because both the buttons are getting their color property from the same variable _buttonColor. You should use separate variables.